# Trigger several buttons and lines at once D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a group of buttons which all have the same class and are appended to the chart area by D3js. There are 20 buttons within 4 categories: visible,JS,CSS,textarea. What I want to do is: press any one button in the category to toggle all buttons in the category, like in the picture. The lines for the whole category (5 lines) should be toggled as well.

[image]

The code for the chart can be found in codepen: http://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/ZeyRam?editors=0110

And for my buttons:

```
 issue.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)                                    
      .attr("x", width + (margin.right/3) - 15) 
      .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (legendSpace)+i*(legendSpace) - 8; })  // spacing
      .attr("fill",function(d) {
        return d.visible ? color(d.name) : "#F1F1F2"; // If array key "visible" = true then color rect, if not then make it grey 
      })
      .attr("class", "legend-box")

      .on("click", function(d){ // On click make d.visible 
        d.visible = !d.visible; // If array key for this data selection is "visible" = true then make it false, if false then make it true

        maxY = findMaxY(categories); // Find max Y rating value categories data with "visible"; true
        yScale.domain([0,maxY]); // Redefine yAxis domain based on highest y value of categories data with "visible"; true
        svg.select(".y.axis")
          .transition()
          .call(yAxis);   

        issue.select("path")
          .transition()
          .attr("d", function(d){
            return d.visible ? line(d.values) : null; // If d.visible is true then draw line for this d selection
          })
```

Comment: You want just the visual effect, right?

Comment: No, sorry it was not clear. I need the lines to toggle aswell on the chart.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a lot of code to write for just one question, specially *without* your working code. Sorry, I'm out.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added the code.

Comment: Thanks. would you mind suggesting an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your click function set the visible flag on all the lines:

```
  .on("click", function(d){ // On click make d.visible 
    // visible is true if the start of the name matches        
    categories.forEach(function(e){
      e.visible = e.name.slice(0, 5) == d.name.slice(0, 5)
    })
```

http://codepen.io/1wheel/pen/bWYaqE?editors=0011

To turn multiple sections on at once, flip the visible flag for just categories that match:

```
  .on("click", function(d){
    categories.forEach(function(e){
      e.visible = e.name.slice(0, 5) == d.name.slice(0, 5) ? !e.visible : e.visible
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, this really addresses the issue. Question: How do I leave 2 sections on at the same time?